# Space key not working in input control when added inside sap.m.ObjectHeader

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a problem with space key (Space bar) on the keyboard, which doesn't work when I try to type text in `FeedInput` on Fiori Application. It is possible to add empty space in case I press <kbd>Shift + Space</kbd>. This combination works on PC, but not on mobile devices.

[image: Fiori application view]

I know that the problem happens because I'm embedding the `FeedInput` inside `<headerContainer>` or some of the other UI elements. It's actually not relevant only for `FeedInput`, but also for `Input`, `SmartField` in `SmartTable`, etc.

I can see that SAP provides the following info for class `sap.m.HeaderContainer`:

> The container that provides a horizontal layout. It provides a horizontal scrolling on the mobile devices. On the desktop, it provides scroll left and scroll right buttons. This control supports keyboard navigation. You can use <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> to navigate through the inner content. The <kbd>Home</kbd> key puts focus on the first control and the <kbd>End</kbd> key puts focus on the last control. Use <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> key to choose the control. <sup>[(source)](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.HeaderContainer)</sup>

I found that if I delete event listener in browser debugger for `KEYPRESS body#content.sapUiBody`, the space bar starts working fine for all type of text fields.

[image: Event handler]

```xml
<ObjectHeader id="ohDetails"
  numberState="Success"
  responsive="true"
>
  <headerContainer>
    <IconTabBar id="itb1"
      select=".onIconTabBarSelect"
      expandable="false"
    >
      <items>
        <!-- ... -->
        <IconTabFilter id="iftLog"
          key="logKey"
          icon="sap-icon://notes"
        >
          <VBox alignContent="End">
            <FeedInput id="fiComment"
              class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom"
              post=".onSubmitComment"
              icon="sap-icon://comment"
              placeholder="{i18n>plhFeedInput}"
            />
            <!-- ... -->
          </VBox>
        </IconTabFilter>
      </items>
    </IconTabBar>
  </headerContainer>
</ObjectHeader>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with putting `<IconTabBar>` as the header container of `<ObjectHeader>`. In fact, the **`<headerContainer>` aggregation awaits `<IconTabBar>` as one of the controls that implements `"sap.m.ObjectHeaderContainer"`.**

The reason why it didn't work was because of the regression introduced with [`commit:d05437d`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/d05437d1d819935f421c370ac33291cea4fdc46d) while trying to prevent scrolling when the space bar was pressed. With [`commit:38f5481`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/38f548146ea5750b2579d38bb00f06f9019f9af7), it's all fixed now.

> - Preventing all pressing of <kbd>SPACE</kbd> when inside `ObjectHeader` caused that, in case there is `Input` field inside `HeaderContainer`, the user couldn't enter space in it.
> - On the other hand, <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is still prevented on all interactive elements of the `ObjectHeader`.

[image: openui5 sapui5 object header space regression fixed]
<sup>Demo: https://jsbin.com/takequm/edit?js,output</sup>

---

**Update:** the fix is now distributed with 1.67+. After updating the UI5 resource bootstrap to, for example, `src="https://ui5.sap.com/1.70.0/resources/sap-ui-core.js"`, we can see that the spacebar works again.